# How to avoid auto-conversion of time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am using rails 2.3.9, ruby 1.9.3, rubygems 1.8.24, MS SQL Server 2008 R2, and Ubuntu Server 11.04.

Here's my problem:

I am passing an xml file through curl to a web api me and my boss developed, but when the file gets processed, the time appears subtracted by eight hours. My time zone is set at GMT+8, meaning the system is auto-converting my time to UTC. How do i fix this so that my time is set to GMT+8?

Here's the XML file:

```
<pos-activity>
<siteId>3</siteId>
<transCode>DEP</transCode>
<supervisorCode>1235</supervisorCode>
<amount type="decimal">5000.0</amount>
<data></data>
<date type="datetime">2012-8-16 20:40:04</date>
</pos-activity>
```

In this example, when this file is processed the resulting time would be 12:40:04 Z

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@sometime.in_time_zone("your time zone")
```

To see a list of time zones, run `rake -D time`

Answer (score 0):

Change config.time_zone to whatever time zone you want in your environment.rb